# Form designer breaks on generic abstract UserControl

Tags: c#, templates, inheritance, windows-forms-designer, partial-classes

I have a generic abstract `UserControl` class, `SensorControl`, which I want all my sensor control panels to inherit from.

### The problem

When attempting to design the `EthernetSensorControl` (one of my inherited UserControl forms, from within Visual Studio, the following error is displayed in the form designer:

> The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: DeviceSensorControl --- The base class 'Engine.Sensors.SensorControl' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.

### `SensorControl` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Engine.Sensors
{
    public abstract class SensorControl<SensorType>
        : UserControl where SensorType : class
    {
        protected SensorType _sensor;
        public SensorControl(SensorType sensor)
        {
            _sensor = sensor;
        }
    }
}
```

### Example inherited class, `EthernetSensorControl`:

```
namespace Engine.Sensors
{
    public partial class EthernetSensorControl
        : SensorControl<EthernetSensor>
    {
        public EthernetSensorControl(EthernetSensor sensor)
            : base(sensor)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

### And the call stack:

> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)

Everything compiles and I can see the panel displayed, but I can't design it. I think the problem may be related to the `partial` classes. Any ideas?

Comment: Its worth noting that the correct terminology is a *Generic* class (not a templated class).  Although the syntax is similar to C++ templated class, they behave fairly differently.

Comment: Duly noted. I come from C++. Fixed my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot design a control or form that inherits an `abstract` class.

(The designer needs to instantiate the base class to serve as the design surface)

The base class also needs to have a parameterless constructor for the designer to call.
This constructor can be private.

Comment: OK. So, I should just add a parameterless constructor to my `SensorControl` class and remove the abstract keyword?

Comment: Removed abstract, added (public) parameterless constructor to both `SensorControl` and `DeviceSensorControl` and I still get the same error.

Comment: Related to this perhaps?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677609/generic-base-class-for-winform-usercontrol