# Rules for Inheriting class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Can I set rules for the class inheriting my base class. eg. `Person : BaseClass`, I want `Person` to implement `iSomeKindOfInterface`, if `Person` does not implement the interface, it is not allowed to inherit from `BaseClass`.

I know this is posibble in generic base classes where you can do the following

```
public BaseClass<T>
     where T : iSomeKinfOfInterface
```

Answer (score 10):

You can implement the interface in your base class and force the inheriting class to supply the implementation:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public abstract class BaseClass : ISomeInterface
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

public class Person : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare your class as

```
abstract BaseClass : ISomeKinfOfInterface
```

Comment: Can not use abstract class. The classes I am  talking about is winforms user controls. When I use an abstract base class, I can not few the user control in the Visual studio designer...

Comment: The error i get in the designer when using generic base class is the same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933218/form-designer-breaks-on-generic-abstract-usercontrol when using abstract classes the error is similar