# Using a base class with a type parameter for a User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, type-parameter

I have a user control and it does not seem to like me using a base class with a type parameter.  Is there any way around this/am I missing something?

```
public partial class PopupSelector : PopupSelectionControl3<int>
{
    public PopupSelector()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

... Plus the designer code ...

public class PopupSelectionControl3<TValue> : XtraUserControl
{
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have an error per se but it won't show me the form in the designer - it still builds and runs fine

Comment: And the designer also has no errors?

Comment: It says that the file cannot be displayed but it doesn't have any compile or run-time errors

Answer (score 0):

The WinForms designer does not cope very well with generic UserControls.

bernhardrusch provides a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677609/generic-base-class-for-winform-usercontrol)

```
public partial class UserControl : UserControlDesignable  {  ... } 

public class UserControlDesignable : BaseUserControl<Someclass> { }
```

More detail on the workaround can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/afdfce40-8d7a-4300-bd8d-26e18c320a71)