# Generic User Control designer error: a new guard page for the stack cannot be created

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I have a Generic UserControl as blow:

```
 public partial class TreeNodeView<C,T>: UserControl 
    {
        public TreeNodeView(C foo, T foo1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Either change the partial class as below:

```
partial class TreeNodeView<C, T>
```

And because get this error in partial designer class:

> Using the generic type 'TreeNodeView' requires 2 type arguments

in line :

```
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = 
new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(TreeNodeView));
```

change it to:

```
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new 
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(TreeNodeView<C,T>));
```

The code compile successful but when want to see the designer i see ma messagebox:

> a new guard page for the stack cannot be created

and when press OK visual studio close immediately. Anybody know whats my wrong?

Comment: Is this WPF? UWP? Winforms?

Comment: @EdPlunkett not WPF, I dont know UWF but i add to a winform project

Comment: OK, it's winforms. Please tag your questions appropriately. This brings them to the attention of people who will best be able to answer them, as well as clarifying exactly what you're asking. If you help people help you, they will be more likely to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't design a control which is a generic type. This is not supported by the WinForms Designer.

Either change your control to a non-generic type and use generic methods instead, or try to design a derived type of which is not generic anymore.

Comment: Your TreeNodeView is a generic type.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677609/generic-base-class-for-winform-usercontrol  or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @ToniWenzel Whats your opinion about the  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677639/4972721) of the question you mention in last comment